# Hadoop :Approach to load Local xml files from Share location to Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, sqoop

My requirement is to load XML files which are collected in to a network share folder by different sources into Hive. I need a confirmation with approach to follow.

As my understanding goes I have to 
1. load all the files into HDFS first 
2. Then using Mapreduce or sqoop transform xml files into required table then I have to load them into Hive.

Please suggest me any better approach if exists.

Answer (score 2):

To proces and read XML files

Mahout has XML input format , see the blog post below to read more

https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java

http://xmlandhadoop.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/xml-processing-in-hadoop.html

Pig has XMLLoader

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/XMLLoader.html

After processing with any of the above approach you can push then to Hive location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you do not required to copy data into the HDFS, you can directly load the data into the hive table using command,

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH 'filepath' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```

filepath can be a

1.relative path, eg: project/data1

2.absolute path, eg: /user/hive/project/data1

3.a full URI with scheme and (optionally) an authority, eg: 
hdfs://namenode:9000/user/hive/project/data1

The target being loaded to can be a table or a partition. If the table is partitioned, then one must specify a specific partition of the table by specifying values for all of the partitioning columns.

filepath can refer to a file (in which case hive will move the file into the table) or it can be a directory (in which case hive will move all the files within that directory into the table). In either case filepath addresses a set of files.

If the keyword LOCAL is specified, then:
1.the load command will look for filepath in the local file system. If a relative path is specified - it will be interpreted relative to the current directory of the user. User can specify a full URI for local files as well - for example: file:///user/hive/project/data1

2.the load command will try to copy all the files addressed by filepath to the target filesystem. The target file system is inferred by looking at the location attribute of the table. The copied data files will then be moved to the table.

If the keyword LOCAL is not specified, then 
Hive will either use the full URI of filepath if one is specified. Otherwise the following rules are applied:

1. If scheme or authority are not specified, Hive will use the scheme and authority from hadoop configuration variable fs.default.name that specifies the Namenode URI.
2. If the path is not absolute - then Hive will interpret it relative to /user/
3. Hive will move the files addressed by filepath into the table (or partition)

if the OVERWRITE keyword is used then the contents of the target table (or partition) will be deleted and replaced with the files referred to by filepath. Otherwise the files referred by filepath will be added to the table.

1. Note that if the target table (or partition) already has a file whose name collides with any of the filenames contained in filepath - then the existing file will be replaced with the new file.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking time to reply. I am not sure how Hive will handle xml files. Can you help me loading xml files.